# Suitable non parametric test

Tags: self-study, nonparametric

I am trying to determine which type of non-parametric test is most suitable in this situation:

Public and private sector organisations were sampled in a study which aimed to determine what percentage of budget was spent on IT systems and technology upgrades in the previous fiscal year. Results were as below:

Sector      % of budget

Public  2.58 5.05 0.05 2.10 4.30 2.25 2.50 1.95 2.33

Private 5.40 2.55 9.00 10.55 1.02 5.11 24.42 1.67 3.33

What kind of test can I use to determine whether the percentage expenditure is greater for the private than the public sector?

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the `[self-study]`
tag & read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with a Wilcoxon Rank Sum test. If you are using R you can run

```
wilcox.test(privatedata,publicdata,alternative="greater")
```

And this should produce the results your looking for.

Comment: @JohnGarrigan no problem, please mark it as solved.